# Design Tab Control with Visual Studio 2008 (without SP1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Is there **any** way (maybe directly editing resource files) to configure a Tab Control (add/remove tabs and their captions and contents) at **design time** with Visual Studio 2008 without SP1 (I heard that SP1 has such feature)?
P.S.: I use c++ with wtl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. The dialog script does not support the Tab control directly, instead, it inserts a generic "CONTROL" statement in which the control "SysTabControl32" is inserted. You need to assign the pages in code.

The new feature in VS 2008 SP1 has to do with the WPF controls, but since you mention that you work with WTL I assume you work with win32 dialog resources.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The form designer for Windows Forms applications allows you to configure the tab control at design time, but the resource editor for native C++ applications doesn't allow this. You can only add tabs to the tab control at run time. (I'm using VS2008 SP1.)